# Using algorithms in papers in my code

Tags: licensing

For example a new research paper comes out and it describes some algorithm, say this is a cutting edge algorithm and came out last week, is there anything stopping me from using that algorithm in my codebase that is for commercial purposes?

What if the paper includes some code and I use that code? There does not seem to be any information about code licensing on the paper so I am not sure how this is meant to work.

Comment: This question is a legal question and thus off-topic here.

Comment: I suggest you direct that question as well to the author of that paper. It's more interesting what that person allows you to do with the code and if that person even can allow you so. Also you have not written about the kind of use of that code you're talking. Are you modifying that code to work in some file of your new software? You need to be more precise with that, especially when you finally go to some lawyer to clarify this. At least she will need to know about which kind of use you're talking specifically and what is done with the new software then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are free to use it unless it is a patented or copyrighted work. Usually such work won't be published, or not all necessary reproducing the work details will be available in the publication. 
However, one must follow the code of ethics and cite the publication in their work to avoid plagiarism. I wouldn't encourage using of the same code myself.
However, there could be legal issues associated with this, and this is not a right place to ask this question.

Comment: Thanks, how can I tell if its patented? is there some place where I can check or it would state on the paper itself?

Comment: I made some edits in my answer which might answer your question. Additionally, is it mentioned anywhere in the publication the reproducing this work is prohibited?

Comment: You can't tell if something is patented except by searching the patent database.

Comment: This answer is merely stupid and a good example of bad advice. Most likely the publication itself (The Paper) is a copyright-able work and as it is published (otherwise the code and the rest of the paper could not be asked about here) copyright applies. And the most important part with this is: It's not that you need to write that something is prohibited because by default it is prohibited (or limited) to copy and transform that publication, e.g. typing that code - modified or not - into a file on your computer.

Comment: In my answer, I clearly mentioned "unless it is patented or copyrighted". There are open access publications that are NOT copyrighted and are often used for commercial / academic research. I do not see the point why anyone would defer from using it! Isn't that the purpose of publication? However, the policies are strictly different for patented and copyrighted work, and will vary based on publishers. My answer was pertaining to non-copyrighted / non-patented work, and the premise of the other answer is works which are copyrighted / patented.

Comment: @ND_27: Which hardly makes not much sense as *any* work is copyrighted. This inherently applies to Open Access as well. So in percentage, how likely would it be that the paper you are answering here about is copyrighted? I'd say it is 99.999999999999999%. What is your assumption? That unless you argue for is that thin, it will be hard to spot. Albeit for the OP, it sounds like that there is nothing to care about.

Answer (score 3):

> *In difference to [the given and accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19070662/367456), just to prevent some poor souls who run over this question to not do wrong decisions too easily:*

***No***, you can not use that code until you have clarified the licensing terms. So for you, as you  don't have any licensing terms, all you can assume is that there are *"all rights reserved"*.

You solve that by trying to find out who the copyright holder of that code-fragment actually and then ask for the licensing. The person who wrote the paper probably is able to tell you. I can not say to you if she is willing though to tell you.

---

> What if the paper includes some code and I use that code?

You have copied that code. You also have changed the work, you translated it from a printed work into a digital file on your computer most likely.

> There does not seem to be any information about code licensing on the paper so I am not sure how this is meant to work.

Well, the reproduction of a work  (for example translation) is only allowed if the copyright holder granted you a (at least limited) right to do so.

As you write that there is no information about the code-licensing given, then you perhaps (I don't know so I can only assume) have no right at all to "use" that code (if using means to type it from the paper into your project).

For the code licensing itself, it's perhaps only used in that publication to give an example, a quote from an existing copyrighted work, used under fair-use. No information must be given about it, and you can safely assume that there is all rights reserved on anything you see there unless you *know* otherwise. Which is not the case, so clarify with author(s) and copyright-holder(s) first.